# Spring Batch - need to initiate process job or step from

Tags: spring-batch

In a job I am using MultiResourceItemReader to read files from folder, in the processor of this job I am need to invoke (initiate) a Job(to process file) for each file available it the folder.

I am not sure whether I should be having it as a Job or a Step. So I need to programmatically start a Job or Step.(which in turn triggers multiple steps) 
in my MultiResourceItemReaderJob's processor
Please let me know how I can do it. any possible links/sample code will help.
Thank you very much

Comment: Just to confirm your use case, you have a folder of files and you need to process each file with it's own job instance?  Is there a reason you can't just iterate over the files in a single job?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Its like for one file type - there are 2 files one file containing details of the the second file(like filename of second file,number of records etc.) based on the file name we need to process second file( iterating 2 files for one file type) and there could be many sets of 2 (same type of files in folder),its POC, so we will have many other file types in the same folder.we are thinking using one job for each file type

Comment: Please suggest how to do.If I need to iterate over files in a single job.Please suggest where do I put this logic for iterating over files in a single job and how do I invoke the job from this iterative logic.